# Fixing "ImportError: No module named qgis.core"?

Tags: pyqgis, importerror

First of all, I'm using Python 2.7.3, QGIS 1.8 (Lisboa) on Windows 7 pro 64 bits.  Now let's go to the actual question:

I have written some code (Python) that works well within the QGIS built in Python console, but now I need to run it from outside QGIS (it is too much to ask for the final user to open QGIS, then the python console and to copy and paste the code).

I have been trying to access the QGIS API, but it is missing from my PYTHONPATH. I've tried whatever is on the instructions, plus a bunch of paths like:
 C:\Program Files(x86)\QGIS\apps\qgis\python\qgis and  C:\Program Files(x86)\QGIS\apps\qgis\python. My result so far is always the same:

```
import qgis.core
ImportError: No module named qgis.core
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I don't know if this is just a typo, but there should be a space between "Files" and "(x86)". Like so: `C:\Program Files (x86)`

Answer (score 5):

It is possible that you have a separate Python installation on your system in addition to Python being bundled with QGIS and PyQGIS is installed only for the bundled Python.

Check if you have two separate Python installations and if you do, try running the script by specifying the full path to the Python executable under the QGIS installation. If that works you'd need to make sure that the PYTHONPATH and/or PATH variables first find the Python under QGIS, because (as far as I know) PATH is only checked until it encounters the first instance of whatever is being looked for...

Answer (score 4):

For new users reading this post, you can find a way of solving errors about importing qgis modules on Windows 7 at [Problem with import qgis.core when writing a stand-alone PyQGIS script](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/129959/problem-with-import-qgis-core-when-writing-a-stand-alone-python-script-that-uses/130102#130102).

Answer (score 3):

Add this to PATH variable (replace "C:\Program Files\QGIS Valmiera" with QGIS install location):

> C:\Program Files\QGIS Valmiera\bin;C:\Program Files\QGIS
>   Valmiera\apps\qgis\bin

and this to PYTHONPATH variable:

> C:\Program Files\QGIS Valmiera\apps\qgis\python;
>   C:\Program Files\QGIS Valmiera\apps\qgis\python\plugins;
>   C:\Program Files\QGIS Valmiera\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me from [A note on configuring your IDE on Windows](http://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/ide_debugging.html#id1) and tere is available information for Eclipse and Pydev, I just like using Pyscripter

If you used the OSGeo4W Installer, you can find this under the bin folder of your OSGeo4W install. Look for something like C:\OSGeo4W\bin\qgis-unstable.bat.

- For using Pyscripter IDE, here’s what you have to do:
- Make a copy of qgis-unstable.bat and rename it pyscripter.bat.
- Open it in an editor. And remove the last line, the one that starts
  QGIS.
- Add a line that points to your Pyscripter executable and add the
  commandline argument that sets the version of Python to be used (2.7
  in the case of QGIS >= 2.0)
- Also add the argument that points to the folder where Pyscripter can
  find the Python dll used by QGIS, you can find this under the bin
  folder of your OSGeoW install

  @echo off

  SET OSGEO4W_ROOT=C:\OSGeo4W

  call "%OSGEO4W_ROOT%"\bin\o4w_env.bat

  call "%OSGEO4W_ROOT%"\bin\gdal16.bat

  @echo off

  path %PATH%;%GISBASE%\bin

Start C:\pyscripter\pyscripter.exe --python25 --pythondllpath=C:\OSGeo4W\bin
Start `C:\pyscripter\pyscripter.exe --python25 --pythondllpath=C:\OSGeo4W\bin`
Now when you double click this batch file it will start Pyscripter, with the correct path.

Comment: A link to a very similar blog note written the same day : https://mapoholic.wordpress.com/2012/06/28/configure-pyscripter-qgis/

Comment: And surprisingly after this post

Answer (score 1):

I tried to write a stand alone python script to use QGIS and encountered the same issue. I was using Ubuntu 20.04 and the QGIS version was version 3 family. The solution was:

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0,"/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages")
import qgis
```

Note that you can use "Import qgis" after using the "sys.path.insert" command line.
Thanks to this [link](https://subscription.packtpub.com/book/application-development/9781783984985/1/ch01lvl1sec10/installing-qgis-for-development). I have found this solution from the link.