# Importing qgis.core when writing standalone PyQGIS script

Tags: pyqgis, windows, importerror

I am trying to write a standalone Python script in windows 7 that uses qgis.core and various other qgis libraries.

I have found an old question on this subject at [Writing standalone Python scripts using PyQGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/30063) and was following its advice, by using the guide at http://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/intro.html#python-applications

The code suggested there  is:

```
set PYTHONPATH=c:\qgispath\python
```

followed by:

```
set PATH=C:\qgispath;%PATH%
```

I found that IDLE did not like the "set at the beggining, so my code looks like this:

```
PYTHONPATH="C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\qgis\python"
PATH="C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\qgis\python\qgis\core;%PATH%"
import qgis.core
```

and I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#15>", line 1, in <module>
    import qgis.core
ImportError: No module named qgis.core
```

I have tried every variant of the paths I can think of including removing the ;%PATH%" at the end (that looks a bit superfluous) but have not been able to find any more information.

Does anyone have any idea where I might be going wrong?

---

After seeing Luigi Pirelli's comment I have now tried:

```
>>> PYTHONPATH="C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/qgis/./python\qgis"
>>> import qgis.core

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
    import qgis.core
ImportError: No module named qgis.core
>>> PATH="C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\qgis\python\qgis\core;%PATH%"
>>> import qgis.core

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#3>", line 1, in <module>
    import qgis.core
ImportError: No module named qgis.core
>>> PATH="C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\core;%PATH%"
>>> import qgis.core

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#6>", line 1, in <module>
    import qgis.core
ImportError: No module named qgis.core
>>>
```

Comment: Can you please modify the title of your question the way it would outline the exact issue you are facing?

Comment: set PYTHONPATH as the value that you can read typing "qgis" in the QGIS Python Console... what is the value?
In my case:
<module 'qgis' from 'C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/qgis-dev/./python\qgis\__init__.pyc'>
=> I've to add to PYTHONPATH the path:
"C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/qgis-dev/./python\qgis"

Comment: Title amended, thanks, I will try this and report back in the main body of the question

Comment: Still no luck, I have tried many permutations of PATH and PYTHONPATH to no avail.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you have installed QGIS via OSGeo4W, I suggest you to follow this work flow (I've just tested it on Windows 7):

1. **Open the OSGeo4W Shell**. `Start->All programs->OSGeo4W->OSGeo4W
   Shell`.
2. **Set environment variables**. My preferred way is to execute [this bat file](http://downloads.tuxfamily.org/tuxgis/geoblogs/configuracion_pyqgis_windows/var_entorno_osgeo4w.bat) (updated 2016.11.03: [this bat file](http://downloads.tuxfamily.org/tuxgis/geoblogs/configuracion_pyqgis_windows/env_var_qgis.bat)) from the OSGeo4W Shell. As you can see, the file sets environment variables in this way:

   ```
   set PYTHONPATH=%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\\apps\\qgis\\python
   set PATH=%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\\apps\\qgis\\bin;%PATH%
   ```

   Of course, you need to check by yourself that those paths exist in your OS and adjust them if necessary.

   So, download the .bat file and execute it by accessing it from the OSGeo4W Shell and pressing ENTER.

   [image]
3. Import PyQGIS libraries by one of the following methods:

   a. **Enter the Python interpreter.** Run `python` in the OSGeo4W Shell and import the libraries manually.

   [image]

   b. **Execute a Python script.** Run `python my_pyqgis_script.py` in the OSGeo4W Shell. I'd start with [a very simple one](http://downloads.tuxfamily.org/tuxgis/geoblogs/configuracion_pyqgis_windows/my_pyqgis_script.py).

   [image]

The work flow was posted (in Spanish) several years ago in [GeoTux](http://geotux.tuxfamily.org/index.php/es/geo-blogs/item/253-configurando-el-entorno-de-desarrollo-para-pyqgis-en-windows#actualizacion1) and still works. As you can see, I do not include environment variables in the Python script, but set them in the OSGeo4W Shell.

Comment: Hi! I have a doubt about that. Why var_entorno_osgeo4w.bat? I did all this lines but in this parte gives me an error. Also I read in these help foruns and I still get the import qgis.core error (run in osgeo4w shell).

Comment: Because that's the name of the file that I'm providing you with to set environment variables. So, you go to the folder where that .bat file is located (in the images you see it is located in `C:\dllo` ) and run the .bat file by writing the name of the file and pressing Enter.

Comment: I tried to use the solution above - I tried to run the my_pygis_script.py and get an import error: No module named qgis.core. How can I fix this?

Comment: I also tried to import qgis.core in pyscripter, and I get another import error: no module named sip

Comment: @kflaw I suggest you to open a new question in GIS.SE describing your problem.

Comment: I tried it as well, everything goes fine until the last step.

Comment: @Geosphere Strange, I'll double check it to see if something was omitted, and will update the instructions if needed.

Comment: Anyhow, I switched to Linux as I have that possibility. In my case, I believe that I hindered too much with PYTHONPATH, already have 3 packages installed (ArcGIS Python, 2.7.8, 3.4, 4 if you include the QGIS one).

Comment: @gcarrillo Actually, up to a point it does work, if you keep using the AdminOSGeoW Shell. I had problems with the last step, running the script.

Comment: I get 'No module named qgis.core' if I try the method suggested here. If I use the python.exe within qgis/bin as an interpreter I get the 'no module named site' error when I try to import qgis.core. I've wasted many hours trying to use pyqgis.

Comment: @Germán Carrillo, this solution works only with the 32bit OSGeo4W Installer (or 32bit QGIS Standalone Installer), not with the 64bit version.

Comment: @RaluBur Just tested it with this installer: QGIS-OSGeo4W-2.14.1-1-Setup-x86_64, and it worked like a charm!

Comment: I've just updated the .bat file (step 2) to a more recent version (just tested it with QGIS 2.16). Please double check to see if it now works for you.

Comment: Germán Carrillo, sorry, i didnt understand how to do it- i get "access denied " in the OSGEO4w

Comment: @GermánCarrillo Hi i followed your answer , but i am not getting it .Please look into this https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/297428/executing-standalone-python-script-using-pyqgis-from-osgeo4w-shell

Answer (score 9):

I've just been wrestling with a similar problem, and noticed a batch file in the OSGeo4W\bin folder called ***python-qgis.bat***. This is part of an OSGeo4W package based install of QGIS 2.18.15 x64 on Windows 10.

When executed, this batch file opens the Python interpreter. `import qgis` successfully runs from within.

This batch file contains the line (as noted by Germán Carrillo in his original answer):

`set PYTHONPATH=%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\qgis\python;%PYTHONPATH%`

just before the python interpreter is launched.

Comment: this takes off the pain of manually configuring the environment variables, thanks

Comment: This seems to start working but than throws an error "SyntaxError: invalid syntax" when running C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python37\lib\site.py

Comment: Reason I got that error is because I wasn't running the python that QGIS is using. Works now!

Answer (score 4):

If you want to have a clear project to perform PyQGIS development, [Anaconda](https://www.anaconda.com/) is the best way to construct it.
Once anaconda is installed you can create a project for PyQGIS by following those steps : 
1. Activate the base environment if it's not ( '(base)' prefix at the left)

```
conda activate
```

2. Create a conda environment for PyQGIS development :

```
conda create -n pyqgis-dev
```

3. Activate the new environment

```
conda activate pyqgis-dev
```

4. Install QGIS through anaconda in the new environment, for example the 3.4 version :

```
conda install -c conda-forge qgis=3.4
```

5. Type 'y' and press enter :

   ```
   Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
   Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
   Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
   Solving environment: done


   ==> WARNING: A newer version of conda exists. <==
     current version: 4.7.12
     latest version: 4.8.2

   Please update conda by running

   $ conda update -n base -c defaults conda



   ## Package Plan ##

   environment location: C:\Users\e.conte\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\pyqgis-dev

   added / updated specs:
     - qgis=3.4


   The following packages will be downloaded:

      package                    |            build
   ---------------------------|-----------------
   pycparser-2.19             |             py_2          88 KB  conda-forge
   ------------------------------------------------------------
                                          Total:          88 KB

   The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:

     boost-cpp          conda-forge/win-64::boost-cpp-1.70.0-h6a4c333_2
     bzip2              conda-forge/win-64::bzip2-1.0.8-hfa6e2cd_2
     ca-certificates    conda-forge/win-64::ca-certificates-2019.11.28-hecc5488_0
     certifi            conda-forge/win-64::certifi-2019.11.28-py37_0
     cffi               conda-forge/win-64::cffi-1.13.2-py37hb32ad35_0
     cfitsio            conda-forge/win-64::cfitsio-3.470-hfa6e2cd_2
     chardet            conda-forge/win-64::chardet-3.0.4-py37_1003
     coverage           conda-forge/win-64::coverage-5.0.3-py37hfa6e2cd_0
     cryptography       conda-forge/win-64::cryptography-2.8-py37hb32ad35_1
     curl               conda-forge/win-64::curl-7.68.0-h4496350_0
     expat              conda-forge/win-64::expat-2.2.9-he025d50_2
     freetype           conda-forge/win-64::freetype-2.10.0-h563cfd7_1
     freexl             conda-forge/win-64::freexl-1.0.5-hd288d7e_1002
     future             conda-forge/win-64::future-0.18.2-py37_0
     gdal               conda-forge/win-64::gdal-2.4.2-py37he6b6c38_4
     geos               conda-forge/win-64::geos-3.7.2-he025d50_2
     geotiff            conda-forge/win-64::geotiff-1.5.1-h8f84788_2
     gettext            conda-forge/win-64::gettext-0.19.8.1-hb01d8f6_1002
     glib               conda-forge/win-64::glib-2.58.3-py37hc0c2ac7_1002
     gsl                conda-forge/win-64::gsl-2.5-h631dd0c_1
     hdf4               conda-forge/win-64::hdf4-4.2.13-hf8e6fe8_1003
     hdf5               conda-forge/win-64::hdf5-1.10.5-nompi_ha405e13_1104
     httplib2           conda-forge/win-64::httplib2-0.17.0-py37_0
     icu                conda-forge/win-64::icu-64.2-he025d50_1
     idna               conda-forge/win-64::idna-2.8-py37_1000
     intel-openmp       pkgs/main/win-64::intel-openmp-2019.4-245
     jinja2             conda-forge/noarch::jinja2-2.11.1-py_0
     jpeg               conda-forge/win-64::jpeg-9c-hfa6e2cd_1001
     kealib             conda-forge/win-64::kealib-1.4.10-hf7dc31f_1005
     krb5               conda-forge/win-64::krb5-1.16.4-hdd46e55_0
     libblas            conda-forge/win-64::libblas-3.8.0-14_mkl
     libcblas           conda-forge/win-64::libcblas-3.8.0-14_mkl
     libcurl            conda-forge/win-64::libcurl-7.68.0-h4496350_0
     libffi             conda-forge/win-64::libffi-3.2.1-h6538335_1006
     libgdal            conda-forge/win-64::libgdal-2.4.2-h2bdb96c_4
     libiconv           conda-forge/win-64::libiconv-1.15-hfa6e2cd_1005
     libkml             conda-forge/win-64::libkml-1.3.0-h4ece8bf_1010
     liblapack          conda-forge/win-64::liblapack-3.8.0-14_mkl
     libnetcdf          conda-forge/win-64::libnetcdf-4.6.2-h376842a_1003
     libpng             conda-forge/win-64::libpng-1.6.37-h7602738_0
     libpq              conda-forge/win-64::libpq-11.5-hb0bdaea_2
     libspatialindex    conda-forge/win-64::libspatialindex-1.9.3-he025d50_3
     libspatialite      conda-forge/win-64::libspatialite-4.3.0a-h832c139_1029
     libssh2            conda-forge/win-64::libssh2-1.8.2-h642c060_2
     libtiff            conda-forge/win-64::libtiff-4.1.0-h21b02b4_3
     libxml2            conda-forge/win-64::libxml2-2.9.10-h9ce36c8_0
     libzip             conda-forge/win-64::libzip-1.5.1-h8f0db0c_1005
     lz4-c              conda-forge/win-64::lz4-c-1.8.3-he025d50_1001
     m2w64-expat        pkgs/msys2/win-64::m2w64-expat-2.1.1-2
     m2w64-gcc-libgfor~ pkgs/msys2/win-64::m2w64-gcc-libgfortran-5.3.0-6
     m2w64-gcc-libs     pkgs/msys2/win-64::m2w64-gcc-libs-5.3.0-7
     m2w64-gcc-libs-co~ pkgs/msys2/win-64::m2w64-gcc-libs-core-5.3.0-7
     m2w64-gettext      pkgs/msys2/win-64::m2w64-gettext-0.19.7-2
     m2w64-gmp          pkgs/msys2/win-64::m2w64-gmp-6.1.0-2
     m2w64-libiconv     pkgs/msys2/win-64::m2w64-libiconv-1.14-6
     m2w64-libwinpthre~ pkgs/msys2/win-64::m2w64-libwinpthread-git-5.0.0.4634.697f757-2
     m2w64-xz           pkgs/msys2/win-64::m2w64-xz-5.2.2-2
     markupsafe         conda-forge/win-64::markupsafe-1.1.1-py37hfa6e2cd_0
     mkl                pkgs/main/win-64::mkl-2019.4-245
     mock               conda-forge/win-64::mock-3.0.5-py37_0
     msys2-conda-epoch  pkgs/msys2/win-64::msys2-conda-epoch-20160418-1
     nose2              conda-forge/noarch::nose2-0.9.2-py_0
     numpy              conda-forge/win-64::numpy-1.18.1-py37hc71023c_0
     openjpeg           conda-forge/win-64::openjpeg-2.3.1-h57dd2e7_3
     openssl            conda-forge/win-64::openssl-1.1.1d-hfa6e2cd_0
     owslib             conda-forge/noarch::owslib-0.19.1-py_0
     pcre               conda-forge/win-64::pcre-8.44-h6538335_0
     pip                conda-forge/noarch::pip-20.0.2-py_2
     plotly             conda-forge/noarch::plotly-4.5.0-py_0
     poppler            conda-forge/win-64::poppler-0.67.0-h1707e21_8
     poppler-data       conda-forge/noarch::poppler-data-0.4.9-1
     postgresql         conda-forge/win-64::postgresql-11.5-h06f7779_2
     proj4              conda-forge/win-64::proj4-6.1.0-hc2d0af5_2
     psycopg2           conda-forge/win-64::psycopg2-2.8.4-py37hb32ad35_0
     pycparser          conda-forge/noarch::pycparser-2.19-py_2
     pygments           conda-forge/noarch::pygments-2.5.2-py_0
     pyopenssl          conda-forge/win-64::pyopenssl-19.1.0-py37_0
     pyproj             conda-forge/win-64::pyproj-2.2.1-py37h3f740ce_0
     pyqt               conda-forge/win-64::pyqt-5.9.2-py37h6538335_4
     pysocks            conda-forge/win-64::pysocks-1.7.1-py37_0
     python             conda-forge/win-64::python-3.7.6-h5b45d93_2
     python-dateutil    conda-forge/noarch::python-dateutil-2.8.1-py_0
     pytz               conda-forge/noarch::pytz-2019.3-py_0
     pyyaml             conda-forge/win-64::pyyaml-5.3-py37hfa6e2cd_0
     qca                conda-forge/win-64::qca-2.2.1-h1a227db_2
     qgis               conda-forge/win-64::qgis-3.4.14-py37h64d9c6e_0
     qjson              conda-forge/win-64::qjson-0.9.0-h1a227db_1005
     qscintilla2        conda-forge/win-64::qscintilla2-2.11.2-py37h6acbd6c_0
     qt                 conda-forge/win-64::qt-5.9.7-h506e8af_3
     qtkeychain         conda-forge/win-64::qtkeychain-0.9.1-h1a227db_1001
     qtlocation         conda-forge/win-64::qtlocation-5.9.7-he025d50_1
     qwt                conda-forge/win-64::qwt-6.1.4-h1a227db_1003
     qwtpolar           conda-forge/win-64::qwtpolar-1.1.1-h1a227db_6
     requests           conda-forge/win-64::requests-2.22.0-py37_1
     retrying           conda-forge/noarch::retrying-1.3.3-py_2
     setuptools         conda-forge/win-64::setuptools-45.2.0-py37_0
     sip                conda-forge/win-64::sip-4.19.8-py37h6538335_1000
     six                conda-forge/win-64::six-1.14.0-py37_0
     sqlite             conda-forge/win-64::sqlite-3.30.1-hfa6e2cd_0
     tk                 conda-forge/win-64::tk-8.6.10-hfa6e2cd_0
     urllib3            conda-forge/win-64::urllib3-1.25.7-py37_0
     vc                 pkgs/main/win-64::vc-14.1-h0510ff6_4
     vs2015_runtime     pkgs/main/win-64::vs2015_runtime-14.16.27012-hf0eaf9b_1
     wheel              conda-forge/noarch::wheel-0.34.2-py_1
     win_inet_pton      conda-forge/win-64::win_inet_pton-1.1.0-py37_0
     wincertstore       conda-forge/win-64::wincertstore-0.2-py37_1003
     xerces-c           conda-forge/win-64::xerces-c-3.2.2-h6538335_1004
     xz                 conda-forge/win-64::xz-5.2.4-h2fa13f4_1001
     yaml               conda-forge/win-64::yaml-0.2.2-hfa6e2cd_1
     zlib               conda-forge/win-64::zlib-1.2.11-h2fa13f4_1006
     zstd               conda-forge/win-64::zstd-1.4.4-hd8a0e53_1


   Proceed ([y]/n)? y
   ```

   This step basically installed the matching python version with the QGIS version you asked, QGIS in your python environment, all the depedencies that it needs (gdal, geos, psycopg2, sqlite, proj, numpy...), setted up the PYTHONPATH to dll and pyd files. So in just a few seconds you have all you need to develop in PyQGIS.

In the top of all the scripts that you'll write, I recommend you to put this before anything (the processing part is just if you want to use QGIS algorithm such as clip or reprojectlayer :

```
import processing
from qgis.core import QgsApplication
from processing.core.Processing import Processing
from qgis.analysis import QgsNativeAlgorithms


qgs = QgsApplication([], False)
qgs.initQgis()
Processing.initialize()
QgsApplication.processingRegistry().addProvider(QgsNativeAlgorithms())
```

Comment: I second this, it worked for me.