# Efficiently generate Voronoi layers in qgis via Python

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis, voronoi-thiessen

The following python commands both appear to function when called in qgis 2.6 to generate Voronoi diagrams:

```
processing.runalg("qgis:voronoipolygons", pointLayer, 1, None)
processing.runalg("grass:v.voronoi",pointLayer,False,False, bbox,-1,0.0001,0, None)
```

but neither of them seems to work well. The first (qgis) is extremely slow, taking 38 seconds with 180 points vs 2 seconds for the grass method. The qgis method also seems to ignore the output variable when it is specified ("C:/tmp/output.shp" in place of None), but the output layer does appear in the Layers pane so I can iterate through the layers and find it.

The second algorithm seems to ignore the output parameter (again, "C:/tmp/output.shp" in place of None), and no result seems to appear in the layer pane. Trying to use memory:name generated an error message. However, the following results in a temp file path being returned:

```
output = processing.runalg("grass:v.voronoi",PointLayer,False,False, bbox,-1,0.0001,0, None)
print output.output
```

My datasets will have thousands of points, so the qgis library is much too slow and the grass library requires a workaround to get the result out.

Is there a way to make qgis:voronoipolygons run faster?
Is there a syntax I am missing to get the result layer from the algorithm? It will be an intermediate result used for future calculations so memory storage is preferred.

Comment: You can try using `processing.runandload` instead of `processing.runalg`. This should load the result layers from memory.

Comment: Thank you for that. I hadn't heard of that method. Is there a way to get a reference to the output layer in python without assuming that it is the topmost layer?

Comment: If I understand you correctly: for your first command, you can use something like `output_1=processing.runalg(... ` . Then when you call your second command, you can reference the output layer from the first command by using `output_1` as the input layer.

Comment: I guess I was hoping for more of a 'best practice'. The output.output string is in the form of "c:/user/AppData/Local/Temp/processing/c3e39c28ab044c3596d02a24c66f3e79/..."

I would prefer to set my own temp location, or specify the file name, or receive the result in memory as an already-instantiated QgsVectorLayer or similar.

Comment: And trying to use that output temp location, the results are deleted immediately after being created, so opening the layer from that path fails...

Comment: Apologies but I am not an expert in python unfortunately. Hopefully others will be able to advise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Fairly old post but will post a possible answer which would allow you to run algorithms from a script **outside** QGIS. Algorithms **should** run faster as more memory would be available without having QGIS loaded. Note that this assumes you have installed QGIS via the [**OSGeo4W installer**](https://www.qgis.org/en/site/forusers/download.html).*

---

Follow the first couple of steps as described by @gcarrillo here: [Problem with import qgis.core when writing a stand-alone PyQGIS script](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/129959/problem-with-import-qgis-core-when-writing-a-stand-alone-pyqgis-script/130102#130102). I use the .bat file to make life easier.

Once the PATHS are set, type `python` into the command line and then copy/paste the following code (edit paths/parameters etc. to your requirements:

```
import os, sys, glob
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.gui import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *

from os.path import expanduser
home = expanduser("~")

QgsApplication( [], False, home + "/AppData/Local/Temp" )

QgsApplication.setPrefixPath("C://OSGeo4W64//apps//qgis", True)
QgsApplication.initQgis()
app = QApplication([])

sys.path.append(home + '/.qgis2/python/plugins')
from processing.core.Processing import Processing
Processing.initialize()
from processing.tools import *

point_directory = home + "/Desktop/Test//"     # Change to path containing point shapefiles
output = "C:/tmp//"                            # Path to save outputs

os.chdir(point_directory)
for pointLayer in glob.glob("*.shp"):
        output_0=general.runalg("qgis:voronoipolygons", pointLayer, 1, output + pointLayer)
        # For follow-on algorithms, use output_0 as input
        # Can also replace this with grass algorithms
```

I have tested using follow-on algorithms and replaced certain outputs with `None` (if I don't want the output of a certain algorithm) and it works for me. Of course, this would differ from what you require but I hope it helps somewhat :)