# Trouble importing qgis.core python module

Tags: qgis, python, installation, osgeo4w, pyscripter

I am having issues loading the qgis Python modules in the osgeo4w shell. Ultimately I want to work with the modules in pyscripter. I tried the solution mentioned in [Problem with import qgis.core when writing a stand-alone PyQGIS script](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/129959/problem-with-import-qgis-core-when-writing-a-stand-alone-pyqgis-script/130102?noredirect=1#comment198818_130102), by loading the sample my_pyqgis_script.py that was given but got an

> import error: no module named qgis.core.

I also tried importing qgis.core in pyscripter after setting up my python path and path variables but in this case I got another

> import error: no module named sip.

Can anyone help?