# Installing PostGIS Layer Viewer for pgAdmin III

Tags: qgis, postgis, plugins, pgadmin-3, postgis-layer-viewer

I have difficulties installing pgAdmin's plugin **PostGIS Layer Viewer**. The official repository on GitHub gives [this Web site](http://geotux.tuxfamily.org/index.php/en/geo-blogs/item/293-consola-sql-para-plugin-pgadmin-postgis-viewer/) for install procedure, then the former site gives [this Web site](http://geotux.tuxfamily.org/index.php/es/geo-blogs/item/253-configurando-el-entorno-de-desarrollo-para-pyqgis-en-windows#actualizacion1) for installing prerequisites.

I have well installed QGIS 2.8 through OSGeo4W. I have problems executing the python script that says `from qgis.core import *`, etc. See error message below:

[image]

I get the 'No module named...' message for either `qgis.core`, `qgis.gui`, `PyQt4.QtCore` and `PyQt4.QtGui`.

Could anybody help me?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2738879/cannot-import-pyqt4-qtgui

Comment: Sorry for the down-vote but it seems to me that this thread mixes up two totally different topics. It's not clear to me what should be the focus of the question.

Comment: OK thank you for the down-vote and the comment that is trully helpful. Have a good day!

Comment: Please follow the steps I gave at [Problem with import qgis.core when writing a stand-alone PyQGIS script](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/129959/problem-with-import-qgis-core-when-writing-a-stand-alone-pyqgis-script/130102#130102), and let me know if that enables you to run the postgis_viewer.py script.