# use gdal python bindings from the QGIS folder in a custom script

Tags: qgis, python, gdal, pyqgis

I have QGIS installed (on Windows) and can import this line from the QGIS Python console:

```
from osgeo import gdal
```

When I try the import in a python file it doesn't work

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/xxx/loader.py", line 6, in <module>
    from osgeo import gdal
ImportError: No module named osgeo
```

How can I use the osgeo lib outside from qgis?

Comment: Have you tried repeating your steps using the **OSGeo4W Shell** command prompt? Type in `python` and enter the path to your python script.

Comment: Please follow the steps indicated at http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/129959/problem-with-import-qgis-core-when-writing-a-stand-alone-pyqgis-script/130102#130102 and let me know if it worked.

Answer (score 1):

i don't recall all the steps i used, but with the anaconda distro, i placed a text file (something like qgislibs.pth) within my anaconda directory (or you default python install) - within the text file, include the path to your osgeo4w site packages - probably like C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\Python27\Lib\site-packages\

i think i also had to include a path in the system environment variables to point to the gdal binaries - something like C:\OSGeo4W\bin

i doubt that's fool proof everywhere, but it's working for me.