# import qgis.core problem with QgsFeature and QgsGeometry ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis

I've tried several previous answers to similar questions - no luck.
I've tried everything, nothing seems to work. This is the error I'm getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Projects\Python\test\script.py", line 3, in <module>
    from qgis.core import QgsApplication
  File "C:\Program Files\QGIS Wien\apps\qgis\python\qgis\__init__.py", line 36, in <module>
    from qgis.core import QgsFeature, QgsGeometry
  File "C:\Program Files\QGIS Wien\apps\qgis\python\qgis\core\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from qgis._core import *
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found.
```

My `PYTHONPATH` contains

```
C:\Program Files\QGIS Wien;C:\Program Files\QGIS Wien\lib;C:\Program Files\QGIS Wien\bin;C:\Program Files\QGIS Wien\apps\qgis\python\plugins;C:\Program Files\QGIS Wien\apps\Python27;C:\Program Files\QGIS Wien\apps\Python27\Lib;C:\Program Files\QGIS Wien\apps\Python27\Lib\site-packages;C:\Program Files\QGIS Wien\apps\qg is\python;C:\Program Files\QGIS Wien\apps\Python27\DLLs;C:\Program Files\QGIS Wi en\apps\qgis\bin;C:\Program Files\QGIS Wien\apps\qgis\plugins;C:\Program Files\QGIS Wien\bin\gdalplugins;C:\Program Files\QGIS Wien\apps\saga\modules;C:\Program Files\QGIS Wien\apps\Qt4\plugins;C:\Program Files\QGIS Wien\apps\grass\grass-6.4.3\lib;C:\Program Files\QGIS Wien\apps\grass\grass-6.4.3\bin;
```

My `PATH` variable also contains all the paths of `PYTHONPATH`. I don't know what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Have you tried to launch the OSGEO4W shell window?

Comment: No, i did not. I am very new to python and QGIS.

Comment: Please follow the steps I gave at http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/129959/problem-with-import-qgis-core-when-writing-a-stand-alone-pyqgis-script/130102#130102 and let me know if it solves your problem.

Comment: Germán Carrillo's solution works with the 32bit OSGeo4W Installer (or 32bit QGIS Standalone Installer), not with the 64bit version.

Comment: Download [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) and point it at `C:\Program Files\QGIS Wien\apps\qgis\python\qgis\_core.pyd`

Comment: @RaluBur, I've tested such solution on 64 bits as well.

Answer (score 2):

for me, this one seems to work:
https://www.resolveask.com/questions/109377/importerror-dll-load-failed-the-specified-procedure-could-not-be-found

```
call "C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\bin\o4w_env.bat"

path %OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\qgis\bin;%PATH%
set QGIS_PREFIX_PATH=%OSGEO4W_ROOT:\=/%/apps/qgis
set PYTHONPATH=%PYTHONPATH%;C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\apps\qgis\python;C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\apps\qgis\python\plugins
set PATH=%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\\apps\\qgis\\bin;%PATH%
SET PYTHONHOME=%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\Python27
```