# How to update geopackage row values?

Tags: python, geopackage

I am looking to update row values within specific fields of a polygon geopackage using an `if` statement--similar to how Esri users would use an Update Cursor . For example, say there is a text field called `campsite` with values ranging from 1W - 10W. I would like to change the value `10W` to `20`.

There is an [example](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/183873/8104) provided by @gene which seems to write a single value for each row in the attributes.

```
for feature in fiona.open(a shapefile): # = for row in cursor:
    feature['properties']['Elevation']= 15 # = row[1] = 15
```

However, when I implement the solution using a geopackage the attributes do not change. Here is my attempt:

```
import fiona

gpkg = r'/path/to/campsites.gpkg'

for feature in fiona.open(gpkg): # = for row in cursor:
    if feature['properties']['Campsite'] == '10W':
        feature['properties']['Campsite'] = '20'
```

How can I update specific row values within a polygon geopackage using if/else control flow?

Comment: Fiona doesn't allow in-place updates, so if you want to update the dataset on disk you'll have to [create a copy](https://fiona.readthedocs.io/en/latest/manual.html#example)