# Calling my Python file from the QGIS Python console?

Tags: qgis, python, qgis-python-console

Situation: I have a Python file called 'Hello.py' and another Python file called 'File1.py'. Hello.py imports File1.py.

Hello.py code is:

```
print 'hello people'
import File1
File1
```

File1.py code is:

```
print 'hello world'
```

The files are located:

```
My files is located C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\PyPack\
```

Using 'OSGeo4W.bat' provided in the QGIS directory, I execute the following commands:

```
C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18>cd C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\PyPack

python Hello.py
```

And the output is:

```
hello people
hello world
```

What do I type in this window to run Hello.py, which gives the output?
[image]

I have tried:

1 - dragging the 'Hello.py' file into the QGIS Python console

2 - the following command:

```
execfile(u'C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\PyPack\Hello.py'.encode('mbcs'))
```

3 - I tried to open 'Hello.py' in the QGIS python editor and run it with the same output.

[image]

And the outputs were:

```
hello people 
Traceback (most recent call last): 
File "<input>", line 1, in <module> 
File "C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\PyPack\Hello.py", line 2, in <module> 
import File1 
File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS2~1.18/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 607, in _import 
mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level) 
ImportError: No module named File1
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1) Just drag the python file to frame of python in QGIS.
2) Another way:

```
execfile(u'C:/hi.py'.encode('mbcs'))
```

To import python modules while working on QGIS, write below lines:

```
import sys 
sys.path 
sys.path.append("C:/PyPack") #Add this folder to python environment path
import File1
```

Comment: That's great, thank you. Is there also a way to call it by typing into the console?

Comment: I updated the question to include imported files. Would you mind please updating your answer if possible?

Comment: @Joe answer updated

Comment: I get this output:
execfile(u'C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\PyPack\Hello.py'.encode('mbcs'))
hello people
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\PyPack\Hello.py", line 2, in <module>
    import File1
  File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS2~1.18/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 607, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
ImportError: No module named File1
......
I might need to update the one of the python files to make the import work in QGIS Python console?

Comment: Have you tested it outside of QGIS ? was is the same case when you dragged the file ?

Comment: Shiko Yes I have. Yes it was the same result when just dragging. I used OSGeo4W.bat, typing in 'python Hello.py' and it works fine. I think there is an issue with QGIS properly importing other files. Might be because it is trying to import the file from some default location?

Comment: Run QGIS as Admin

Comment: Ran QGIS as admin and tried the command and the output was the same. Interestingly I can't drag files into the frame when QGIS is opened as Admin..

Comment: Try to load your python file using the **QGIS python editor** then run and let me know.

Comment: Same output. See end of updated question

Comment: Did you check this link http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/129959/problem-with-import-qgis-core-when-writing-a-stand-alone-pyqgis-script

Comment: Thank you for providing the link. I'll review and try it and let you know what happens.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56972/discussion-between-joe-and-shiko).

Answer (score 0):

Python 2 builtin function "execfile" was removed in Python 3.0, now you can use:

```
exec(open(r"C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\PyPack\Hello.py".encode('utf-8')).read())
```

On this line, we open the .py file (assuming it was saved with the usual "utf-8" encoding), then get the content as a string, and finally run the code in the Qgis python console line by line.

Comment: While it's okay to Answer an answered question, you really need to put more than a single line in such an Answer, explaining what is different or better about your solution.

Comment: Done. Thanks @Vince .