# Unable to load shapefile in PyQGIS

Tags: shapefile, pyqgis

I've been trying to load a .shp file using PyQGIS, but layer.isValid() is always false. I've tried looking around at past solutions for the problem and nothing is working for me. This is my code currently:

```
from qgis.core import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import QApplication

app = QApplication([])
QgsApplication.setPrefixPath('C:\\OSGeo4W\\apps\\qgis\\', True)
QgsApplication.initQgis()

layer = QgsVectorLayer('C:\\path\\to\\file.shp', 'name', 'ogr')
print layer.isValid()
```

I've also tried using forward slashes instead of double backslashes in my paths, which doesn't work either. I'm on Windows 10, running Python 2.7.5 with OSGeo4W.

Comment: Can you load the layer in QGIS or any other GIS programs?

Comment: Yes, I'm using in a QGIS project just fine.

Comment: You probably need to set your paths correctly. You could run this [batch file](http://downloads.tuxfamily.org/tuxgis/geoblogs/configuracion_pyqgis_windows/var_entorno_osgeo4w.bat) described in [this post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/129959/problem-with-import-qgis-core-when-writing-a-stand-alone-pyqgis-script/130102#130102) before running your script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the app reference:

```
app = QApplication([])
app.setPrefixPath('C:\\OSGeo4W\\apps\\qgis\\', True)
app.initQgis()
```