# No module named 'qgis' only in IDE?

Tags: pyqgis, installation, anaconda, pycharm

I'm working with pycharm 3.7 on win 8.1 with anaconda. 
Im trying to import qgis with no success. 
after reading this [link](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/129959/problem-with-import-qgis-core-when-writing-a-stand-alone-pyqgis-script/130102#130102) I succeeded to import qgis when runing python from terminal but not from IDE.  It's happen after reading python-qgis.bat from terminal and then execute python from the terminal as well.

phthon-qgis.bat:

```
@echo off
call "%~dp0\o4w_env.bat"
call qt5_env.bat
call py3_env.bat
@echo off
path %OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\qgis\bin;%PATH%
set QGIS_PREFIX_PATH=%OSGEO4W_ROOT:\=/%/apps/qgis
set GDAL_FILENAME_IS_UTF8=YES 
rem Set VSI cache to be used as buffer, see #6448
set VSI_CACHE=TRUE
set VSI_CACHE_SIZE=1000000
set PYTHONPATH=%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\qgis\python;%PYTHONPATH%
"%PYTHONHOME%\python" %*
```

I tried also to add this file path as an enviroment variable in pycharm but it change nothing.

how can I import qgis from my ide?

Comment: read this post https://anitagraser.com/2019/03/03/stand-alone-pyqgis-scripts-with-osgeo4w/

Comment: Thnaks, but I'm not sure that it helps. now i've got errors says "No module named '_tkinter'" and also for  matplotlib.pyplot as plt, switch_backend(rcParams["backend"]) and import tkinter as Tk...it seems that if I fix the qgis problem, the tkinter show up and vice versa..any ideas?

Comment: You missed to launch pycharm.

Comment: @SIGIS what do you mean? I added the lines that start pycharm at the end of the .bat file and also create geosw interpeter throw pycharm