# Calling PyQGIS functions from external editors (Linux)

Tags: pyqgis, linux

Is it possible to integrate external Python editors (such as KDevelop) with QGIS, so that it would be possible to run functions in `qgis.core`, `qgis.utils` etc. outside of the QGIS Python Console?

Following the guidelines on the QGIS website (http://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/intro.html), I tried this, but it just returns 1 and nothing else:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/usr/share/qgis/python')
import qgis.core
import qgis.utils

app = qgis.core.QgsApplication([], True)
qgis.core.QgsApplication.initQgis()
qgis.utils.iface.addVectorLayer("testing.shp", "anewlayer", "ogr") 
aLayer = qgis.utils.iface.activeLayer()
print aLayer.name()
```

Such as:

```
$ LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib64/qgis/ python qgis-test.py && echo "OK" || echo "Died"
Died
```

I am running openSUSE Tumbleweed, 64-bit.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I use following intro for stand-alone applications:

```py
# the_app.py
import os
import sys

from qgis.core import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *     

def main():
    QgsApplication.setPrefixPath(os.environ['QGIS_PREFIX'], True)
    QgsApplication.initQgis()

    # app specific code
    ...

    QgsApplication.exitQgis()
    sys.exit(result)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

When the app do not need a GUI (eg do some geoprocessing), replace the ellipsis with something like that:

```py
# app specific code (console)
print 'starting test'
layer1 = QgsVectorLayer('LineString', 'anewlayer', 'memory')
print layer.isValid()
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(layer1, False)
print 'layer added to map layer registry'
aLayer = QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayersByName('anewlayer')[0]
print aLayer.name()
```

To work with one or more layers you do not have to add them to map layer registry, just reference them by their variable name (here `layer1`).

When you use a GUI, for example a mapper window, this would be a python class derived from QMainWindow, typically designed with QtDesigner. The ellipsis have to be replaced with code as in the next example:

```py
# app specific code (GUI)
app = QApplication(sys.argv)

# create gui window
window = Main()
window.show() 

result = app.exec_()
app.deleteLater()
```

To test this approach without actually having a GUI try this modified console version:

```py
# app specific code (GUI ready)
app = QApplication(sys.argv)

layer1 = QgsVectorLayer('LineString', 'anewlayer', 'memory')
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(layer1, False)
aLayer = QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayersByName('anewlayer')[0]
print aLayer.name()

app.qApp.quit()

result = app.exec_()
app.deleteLater()
```

It is almost the same as the console version (as there are actually no graphical objects), but regard the `quit()` which stops the application.

To start such app on Linux:

```
#!/bin/sh
export PYTHONPATH="/usr/share/qgis/python"
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/lib64/qgis"
export QGIS_PREFIX="/usr"
python the_app.py
```

And on a Windows machine:

```
SET OSGEO4W_ROOT=D:\OSGeo4W64
SET QGISNAME=qgis
SET QGIS=%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\%QGISNAME%
SET QGIS_PREFIX=%QGIS%

CALL %OSGEO4W_ROOT%\bin\o4w_env.bat

SET PATH=%PATH%;%QGIS%\bin
SET PYTHONPATH=%QGIS%\python;%PYTHONPATH%

python the_app.py
```

A very basic GUI may look like this:

```py
# hand-made window with simple toolbar
class Ui_DemoWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, window):
        window.setWindowTitle('Demo')

        self.centralWidget = QWidget(window)
        self.centralWidget.setFixedSize(640, 480)
        window.setCentralWidget(self.centralWidget)
        window.move(0, 0)

        self.layout = QVBoxLayout()    
        self.layout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)    
        self.centralWidget.setLayout(self.layout)

        self.toolBar = QToolBar(window)
        window.addToolBar(Qt.TopToolBarArea, self.toolBar)

        # quit action
        self.actionQuit = QAction('Quit', window)
        self.actionQuit.setShortcut(QKeySequence.Quit)

        # do something, here call function to create some geometries
        self.actionCreateGeom = QAction('Geometry', window)

        # link action to GUI elements
        self.toolBar.addAction(self.actionQuit)
        self.toolBar.addSeparator()
        self.toolBar.addAction(self.actionCreateGeom)


class Main(QMainWindow, Ui_DemoWindow):

    def __init__(self):    
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.canvas = QgsMapCanvas()
        self.layout.addWidget(self.canvas)

        self.connect(self.actionQuit, SIGNAL('triggered()'), self.quit) 
        self.connect(self.actionCreateGeom, SIGNAL('triggered()'), self.some_geoms) 

    # quick and dirty: create layer with some features, add layer
    # to map canvas, and zoom canvas to full view
    def some_geoms(self):
        layer = QgsVectorLayer('LineString', 'anewlayer', 'memory')
        # add some features
        prov = layer.dataProvider()
        feats = []
        feat = QgsFeature()
        feat.setGeometry(QgsGeometry().fromPolyline([QgsPoint(-1,1), QgsPoint(1, -1)]))
        feats.append(feat)
        prov.addFeatures(feats)
        layer.updateExtents()

        QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(layer)
        self.canvas.setLayerSet([QgsMapCanvasLayer(layer)])
        self.canvas.zoomToFullExtent()    

    def quit(self):
        qApp.quit()
```

How its look after pressing button *Geometry*:

[image: demo]

Starting with this simple example you may wish to implement the legend widget, property dialogs, layer dialogs, selection and editing behaviour, and so on.

Comment: Using your code as-is, it doesn't crash any more, but it does result in the script simply idling there forever. It cannot even be stopped by sending SIGINT, it has to be stopped with SIGKILL. Am I still missing something?

Comment: You may run a stand-alone app WITH or WITHOUT a GUI. When you have a GUI, then the GUI gets the control until it ends with a quit(). Initialization of such GUI class would replace the #app specific code in my example. If you do not have a GUI then you cannot use GUI related methods, like activeLayer(). I edit my answer to include an example.

Comment: I tried that (copy-pasted the first part and inserted the GUI block instead of the eliipsis), and got this error: `Traceback (most recent call last):  File "test.py", line 25, in <module>    main()  File "test.py", line 15, in main    window = Main() NameError: global name 'Main' is not defined`

Comment: @GreatEmerald Main() should be just an example. If you have build a GUI with QtDesigner or from scratch then insert this class name instead. Since I dont know your exact app environment    I showed the principles

Comment: Oh, OK. So I'm looking at the wrong example, then. Using the "GUI Ready" example, it seems to work (when I remove `qApp` from `app.qApp.quit()`, since that doesn't exist) as I get the right output, but it doesn't seem to connect or start a visible QGIS instance, so I don't see the layer in it. Also, once again it just gets stuck and I need to kill it, it doesn't actually quit.

Comment: @GreatEmerald No, this script does not start a visible QGIS instance, since the visible part is the GUI. If you want to show the layer, you have to create a window, insert a layout, and add a mapcanvas. But this would be another question, since you initially asked for running QGIS functions. If you like show me your code so I can have a look together with a description what you want to do. You find my email address on my github profile detlevn.

Comment: It's in the question: I want not only to be able to call `qgis.core` functions, but also `qgis.utils.iface` functions, like `qgis.utils.iface.addVectorLayer("testing.shp", "anewlayer", "ogr")`.

Comment: @GreatEmerald As in http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/29580/how-to-run-a-simple-python-script-for-qgis-from-outside-e-g-sublime-text explaned `iface` is only available in QGIS itself. For a standalone application you have to build all interface stuff from scratch using the API (Qgis and Qt). To help you starting I extend the answer to include a very basic Main() class to show some of this API calls.

Comment: I followed the above step but when I run the python file containing pyqgis, it works in pycharm but fails in terminal with `ImportError: No module named qgis.core` error. Could someone please help?

Comment: @wondim Please have a look at https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/40375/fixing-importerror-no-module-named-qgis-core

Comment: @Detlev using /usr/bin/python infront of running the file helped! Thank you!