# QGIS Python Script - print "HELLO QGIS!" using a Windows Batch File (.bat)

Tags: qgis, python, batch

I have a python script (as given below) in QGIS which will just print "Hello QGIS!".

```
import sys
from qgis.core import *

# Initialize QGIS Application
QgsApplication.setPrefixPath("C:/OSGeo4W/apps/qgis", True)
app = QgsApplication([], True)
QgsApplication.initQgis()

# Add the path to Processing framework
sys.path.append('C:/OSGeo4W/apps/qgis/plugins')

# Import and initialize Processing framework
from processing.core.Processing import Processing
Processing.initialize()
import processing

print 'Hello QGIS!'
```

Now, I want to execute this python script without opening QGIS by using a Windows Batch File script. The .bat file which I created for this is given below.

```
REM Change OSGEO4W_ROOT to point to the base install folder
set QGIS_PREFIX_PATH=C:\OSGeo4W\apps\qgis
REM Gdal Setup
set GDAL_DATA=C:\OSGeo4W\share\gdal\
REM Python Setup
set PATH=C:\OSGeo4W\bin;C:\OSGeo4W\apps\qgis\bin;%PATH%
SET PYTHONHOME=C:\OSGeo4W\apps\Python27
set PYTHONPATH=C:\OSGeo4W\apps\qgis\python;%PYTHONPATH%

REM Launch python job
python C:/Users/Sreeraj/.qgis2/processing/scripts/hello.py
pause
```

Unfortunately, I am getting an error :

```
File "C:/Users/Sreeraj/.qgis2/processing/scripts/hello.py", line 13, in <module>
from processing.core.Processing import Processing
ImportError: No module named processing.core.Processing
```

I also tried modifying the .bat file as given below.

```
SET QGIS_PREFIX_PATH=C:\OSGeo4W\apps\qgis
call "C:/OSGeo4W/bin/o4w_env.bat"
SET PYTHONPATH=C:\OSGeo4W\apps\qgis\python;%PYTHONPATH%
SET PATH=%PATH%;C:\OSGeo4W\apps\qgis\bin

cmd /c python "C:/Users/Sreeraj/.qgis2/processing/scripts/hello.py"
```

Again, I am getting the same error :

```
ImportError: No module named processing.core.Processing
```

But, clearly, I have set everything correctly and the processing folder is located in C:/Users/Sreeraj/.qgis2/ .

So, what kind of modification do I have to make in order to run this basic python script correctly using a .bat file ?

Comment: Try replacing `import processing` with `from processing.tools import *`.

Comment: @Joseph I  tried that and it didn't work.

Comment: @Joseph Is there some other folder called 'processing' in any other location ? Currently, I can see a folder named 'processing' in the location C:/Users/Sreeraj/.qgis2/ . And my python script hello.py is saved in the location "C:/Users/Sreeraj/.qgis2/processing/scripts/hello.py"

Comment: @Joseph This processing folder "C:/Users/Sreeraj/.qgis2/processing/" is not in the QGIS_PREFIX_PATH=C:\OSGeo4W\apps\qgis . Will that make a problem ?

Comment: @Joseph No. I am getting the same error ImportError: No module named processing.core.Processing .

Comment: @Joseph You are right !! I have to give sys.path.append("C:/OSGeo4W/apps/qgis/python/plugins") and not sys.path.append("C:/OSGeo4W/apps/qgis/plugins") . It worked perfectly.  It was a very silly and simple mistake from my side. Thank You.

Comment: Most welcome, glad you got it working! Will post the comment as an answer for the convenience of others :)

Comment: may be this answer will help: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/260832/87346

Comment: @eurojam In this case, Joseph 's answer will solve this issue. I have accepted Joseph 's answer. Anyway, thank you for the link since it helped me to gain some more knowledge about this types of tricky issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to replace the following line:

```
sys.path.append('C:/OSGeo4W/apps/qgis/plugins')
```

with:

```
sys.path.append('C:/OSGeo4W/apps/qgis/python/plugins')
```

As this is where the `Processing` functionalities are stored (the path you initially used contains other core plugins)