# Running standalone QGIS model script in Python

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, standalone

I am trying run an exported QGIS model as Python script from Anaconda.

I followed [Executing a standalone QGIS python script on Windows 10](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/260815/executing-a-standalone-qgis-python-script-on-windows-10), and I get no error of modules, when running this I get no error nor output but some warnings of deprecation

```py
import os, sys

# Append QGIS Python library to python search path
sys.path.append(r'C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.6\apps\Python37')

# Append location of DLLs to current system PATH envrionment variable
os.environ['PATH'] += r";C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.6\apps\qgis\python;"
print (os.environ['PATH'])
from qgis.core import QgsProcessing
from qgis.core import QgsProcessingAlgorithm
from qgis.core import QgsProcessingMultiStepFeedback
from qgis.core import QgsProcessingParameterRasterLayer
from qgis.core import QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSink
sys.path.append(r'C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.6\apps\qgis\python\plugins')

import processing

class Trees(QgsProcessingAlgorithm):

    def initAlgorithm(self, config=None):
        self.addParameter(QgsProcessingParameterRasterLayer('dsm', 'DSM', defaultValue="Path/dsm.tif"))
        self.addParameter(QgsProcessingParameterRasterLayer('dtm', 'DTM', defaultValue="Path/dtm.tif"))
        self.addParameter(QgsProcessingParameterRasterLayer('zone', 'Zone', defaultValue="Path/odm_orthophoto.tif"))
        self.addParameter(QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSink('Finaltrees', 'FinalTrees', type=QgsProcessing.TypeVectorAnyGeometry, createByDefault=True, defaultValue='Path/finaltrees.shp'))

    def processAlgorithm(self, parameters, context, model_feedback):
        # Use a multi-step feedback, so that individual child algorithm progress reports are adjusted for the
        # overall progress through the model
        feedback = QgsProcessingMultiStepFeedback(20, model_feedback)
        results = {}
        outputs = {}

        # Heights calculator
        alg_params = {
            'CELLSIZE': None,
            'CRS': None,
            'EXPRESSION': '\"DSM@1\" - \"DTM@1\"',
            'EXTENT': None,
            'LAYERS': parameters['dtm'],
            'OUTPUT': QgsProcessing.TEMPORARY_OUTPUT
        }
        outputs['HeightsCalculator'] = processing.run('qgis:rastercalculator', alg_params, context=context, feedback=feedback, is_child_algorithm=True)

        feedback.setCurrentStep(1)
        if feedback.isCanceled():
            return {}

        # NDVI calculator
        alg_params = {
            'CELLSIZE': 0,
            'CRS': None,
            'EXPRESSION': 'sqrt(256*  \"Zone@2\"- 256 * \"Zone@3\")',
            'EXTENT': None,
            'LAYERS': parameters['dtm'],
            'OUTPUT': QgsProcessing.TEMPORARY_OUTPUT
        }
        outputs['NdviCalculator'] = processing.run('qgis:rastercalculator', alg_params, context=context, feedback=feedback, is_child_algorithm=True)

        feedback.setCurrentStep(2)
        if feedback.isCanceled():
            return {}

        # NDVI Selector
        alg_params = {
            'CELLSIZE': 0,
            'CRS': None,
            'EXPRESSION': '\"\'Output\' from algorithm \'NDVI calculator\'@1\"> 100',
            'EXTENT': None,
            'LAYERS': outputs['NdviCalculator']['OUTPUT'],
            'OUTPUT': QgsProcessing.TEMPORARY_OUTPUT
        }
        outputs['NdviSelector'] = processing.run('qgis:rastercalculator', alg_params, context=context, feedback=feedback, is_child_algorithm=True)

        feedback.setCurrentStep(3)
        if feedback.isCanceled():
            return {}

        # Only NDVI
        alg_params = {
            'CELLSIZE': 0,
            'CRS': None,
            'EXPRESSION': '(\"\'Output\' from algorithm \'NDVI Selector\'@1\" =1)*\"\'Output\' from algorithm \'NDVI Selector\'@1\"',
            'EXTENT': None,
            'LAYERS': outputs['NdviSelector']['OUTPUT'],
            'OUTPUT': QgsProcessing.TEMPORARY_OUTPUT
        }
        outputs['OnlyNdvi'] = processing.run('qgis:rastercalculator', alg_params, context=context, feedback=feedback, is_child_algorithm=True)

        feedback.setCurrentStep(4)
        if feedback.isCanceled():
            return {}

        # Build virtual raster
        alg_params = {
            'ADD_ALPHA': False,
            'ASSIGN_CRS': None,
            'INPUT': outputs['OnlyNdvi']['OUTPUT'],
            'PROJ_DIFFERENCE': False,
            'RESAMPLING': 0,
            'RESOLUTION': 1,
            'SEPARATE': False,
            'SRC_NODATA': '0',
            'OUTPUT': QgsProcessing.TEMPORARY_OUTPUT
        }
        outputs['BuildVirtualRaster'] = processing.run('gdal:buildvirtualraster', alg_params, context=context, feedback=feedback, is_child_algorithm=True)

        feedback.setCurrentStep(5)
        if feedback.isCanceled():
            return {}

        # True NDVI
        alg_params = {
            'CELLSIZE': 0,
            'CRS': None,
            'EXPRESSION': '(\"Zone@4\" -\"Zone@1\" ) /(\"Zone@4\" +\"Zone@1\" )',
            'EXTENT': None,
            'LAYERS': parameters['zone'],
            'OUTPUT': QgsProcessing.TEMPORARY_OUTPUT
        }
        outputs['TrueNdvi'] = processing.run('qgis:rastercalculator', alg_params, context=context, feedback=feedback, is_child_algorithm=True)

        feedback.setCurrentStep(6)
        if feedback.isCanceled():
            return {}

        # Polygonize (raster to vector)
        alg_params = {
            'BAND': 1,
            'EIGHT_CONNECTEDNESS': False,
            'FIELD': 'Value',
            'INPUT': outputs['BuildVirtualRaster']['OUTPUT'],
            'OUTPUT': QgsProcessing.TEMPORARY_OUTPUT
        }
        outputs['PolygonizeRasterToVector'] = processing.run('gdal:polygonize', alg_params, context=context, feedback=feedback, is_child_algorithm=True)

        feedback.setCurrentStep(7)
        if feedback.isCanceled():
            return {}

        # Extract by attribute
        alg_params = {
            'FIELD': 'Value',
            'INPUT': outputs['PolygonizeRasterToVector']['OUTPUT'],
            'OPERATOR': 0,
            'VALUE': '1',
            'OUTPUT': QgsProcessing.TEMPORARY_OUTPUT
        }
        outputs['ExtractByAttribute'] = processing.run('native:extractbyattribute', alg_params, context=context, feedback=feedback, is_child_algorithm=True)

        feedback.setCurrentStep(8)
        if feedback.isCanceled():
            return {}

        # Fix geometries
        alg_params = {
            'INPUT': outputs['ExtractByAttribute']['OUTPUT'],
            'OUTPUT': QgsProcessing.TEMPORARY_OUTPUT
        }
        outputs['FixGeometries'] = processing.run('native:fixgeometries', alg_params, context=context, feedback=feedback, is_child_algorithm=True)

        feedback.setCurrentStep(9)
        if feedback.isCanceled():
            return {}

        # JUSTNDVI
        alg_params = {
            'ALPHA_BAND': False,
            'CROP_TO_CUTLINE': True,
            'DATA_TYPE': 0,
            'INPUT': outputs['TrueNdvi']['OUTPUT'],
            'KEEP_RESOLUTION': False,
            'MASK': outputs['FixGeometries']['OUTPUT'],
            'MULTITHREADING': False,
            'NODATA': None,
            'OPTIONS': '',
            'SET_RESOLUTION': False,
            'SOURCE_CRS': None,
            'TARGET_CRS': None,
            'X_RESOLUTION': None,
            'Y_RESOLUTION': None,
            'OUTPUT': QgsProcessing.TEMPORARY_OUTPUT
        }
        outputs['Justndvi'] = processing.run('gdal:cliprasterbymasklayer', alg_params, context=context, feedback=feedback, is_child_algorithm=True)

        feedback.setCurrentStep(10)
        if feedback.isCanceled():
            return {}

        # NDVIValues
        alg_params = {
            'FIELD_NAME': 'NDVI',
            'INPUT_RASTER': outputs['Justndvi']['OUTPUT'],
            'RASTER_BAND': 1,
            'OUTPUT': QgsProcessing.TEMPORARY_OUTPUT
        }
        outputs['Ndvivalues'] = processing.run('native:pixelstopoints', alg_params, context=context, feedback=feedback, is_child_algorithm=True)

        feedback.setCurrentStep(11)
        if feedback.isCanceled():
            return {}

        # Clip raster by mask layer
        alg_params = {
            'ALPHA_BAND': False,
            'CROP_TO_CUTLINE': True,
            'DATA_TYPE': 0,
            'INPUT': outputs['HeightsCalculator']['OUTPUT'],
            'KEEP_RESOLUTION': False,
            'MASK': outputs['FixGeometries']['OUTPUT'],
            'MULTITHREADING': False,
            'NODATA': None,
            'OPTIONS': '',
            'SET_RESOLUTION': False,
            'SOURCE_CRS': None,
            'TARGET_CRS': None,
            'X_RESOLUTION': None,
            'Y_RESOLUTION': None,
            'OUTPUT': QgsProcessing.TEMPORARY_OUTPUT
        }
        outputs['ClipRasterByMaskLayer'] = processing.run('gdal:cliprasterbymasklayer', alg_params, context=context, feedback=feedback, is_child_algorithm=True)

        feedback.setCurrentStep(12)
        if feedback.isCanceled():
            return {}

        # Mean NDVI
        alg_params = {
            'DISCARD_NONMATCHING': False,
            'INPUT': outputs['FixGeometries']['OUTPUT'],
            'JOIN': outputs['Ndvivalues']['OUTPUT'],
            'JOIN_FIELDS': None,
            'PREDICATE': 1,
            'SUMMARIES': 6,
            'OUTPUT': QgsProcessing.TEMPORARY_OUTPUT
        }
        outputs['MeanNdvi'] = processing.run('qgis:joinbylocationsummary', alg_params, context=context, feedback=feedback, is_child_algorithm=True)

        feedback.setCurrentStep(13)
        if feedback.isCanceled():
            return {}

        # Heights
        alg_params = {
            'FIELD_NAME': 'Height',
            'INPUT_RASTER': outputs['ClipRasterByMaskLayer']['OUTPUT'],
            'RASTER_BAND': 1,
            'OUTPUT': QgsProcessing.TEMPORARY_OUTPUT
        }
        outputs['Heights'] = processing.run('native:pixelstopoints', alg_params, context=context, feedback=feedback, is_child_algorithm=True)

        feedback.setCurrentStep(14)
        if feedback.isCanceled():
            return {}

        # Peaks
        alg_params = {
            'DISCARD_NONMATCHING': True,
            'INPUT': outputs['FixGeometries']['OUTPUT'],
            'JOIN': outputs['Heights']['OUTPUT'],
            'JOIN_FIELDS': None,
            'PREDICATE': 1,
            'SUMMARIES': 3,
            'OUTPUT': QgsProcessing.TEMPORARY_OUTPUT
        }
        outputs['Peaks'] = processing.run('qgis:joinbylocationsummary', alg_params, context=context, feedback=feedback, is_child_algorithm=True)

        feedback.setCurrentStep(15)
        if feedback.isCanceled():
            return {}

        # PeaksnNDVI
        alg_params = {
            'DISCARD_NONMATCHING': True,
            'INPUT': outputs['Peaks']['OUTPUT'],
            'JOIN': outputs['MeanNdvi']['OUTPUT'],
            'JOIN_FIELDS': 'NDVI_mean',
            'METHOD': 1,
            'PREDICATE': 2,
            'PREFIX': '',
            'OUTPUT': QgsProcessing.TEMPORARY_OUTPUT
        }
        outputs['Peaksnndvi'] = processing.run('qgis:joinattributesbylocation', alg_params, context=context, feedback=feedback, is_child_algorithm=True)

        feedback.setCurrentStep(16)
        if feedback.isCanceled():
            return {}

        # Add geometry attributes
        alg_params = {
            'CALC_METHOD': 0,
            'INPUT': outputs['Peaksnndvi']['OUTPUT'],
            'OUTPUT': QgsProcessing.TEMPORARY_OUTPUT
        }
        outputs['AddGeometryAttributes'] = processing.run('qgis:exportaddgeometrycolumns', alg_params, context=context, feedback=feedback, is_child_algorithm=True)

        feedback.setCurrentStep(17)
        if feedback.isCanceled():
            return {}

        # Extract by expression
        alg_params = {
            'EXPRESSION': 'NDVI_mean > 0.2 AND NDVI_mean IS NOT NULL AND Height_max > 1 AND Height_max IS NOT NULL AND area > 1',
            'INPUT': outputs['AddGeometryAttributes']['OUTPUT'],
            'OUTPUT': QgsProcessing.TEMPORARY_OUTPUT
        }
        outputs['ExtractByExpression'] = processing.run('native:extractbyexpression', alg_params, context=context, feedback=feedback, is_child_algorithm=True)

        feedback.setCurrentStep(18)
        if feedback.isCanceled():
            return {}

        # Join attributes by field value
        alg_params = {
            'DISCARD_NONMATCHING': True,
            'FIELD': 'Height',
            'FIELDS_TO_COPY': None,
            'FIELD_2': 'Height_max',
            'INPUT': outputs['Heights']['OUTPUT'],
            'INPUT_2': outputs['ExtractByExpression']['OUTPUT'],
            'METHOD': 1,
            'PREFIX': '',
            'OUTPUT': QgsProcessing.TEMPORARY_OUTPUT
        }
        outputs['JoinAttributesByFieldValue'] = processing.run('native:joinattributestable', alg_params, context=context, feedback=feedback, is_child_algorithm=True)

        feedback.setCurrentStep(19)
        if feedback.isCanceled():
            return {}

        # Delete duplicates by attribute
        alg_params = {
            'FIELDS': 'NDVI_mean',
            'INPUT': outputs['JoinAttributesByFieldValue']['OUTPUT'],
            'OUTPUT': parameters['Finaltrees']
        }
        outputs['DeleteDuplicatesByAttribute'] = processing.run('native:removeduplicatesbyattribute', alg_params, context=context, feedback=feedback, is_child_algorithm=True)
        results['Finaltrees'] = outputs['DeleteDuplicatesByAttribute']['OUTPUT']
        return results

    def name(self):
        return 'trees'

    def displayName(self):
        return 'trees'

    def group(self):
        return ''

    def groupId(self):
        return ''

    def createInstance(self):
        return Trees()
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

With QGIS 3.4 and Windows 10 I have these deprecation warnings when running my standalone application :

```
C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.4\apps\qgis-ltr\python\qgis\utils.py:685: DeprecationWarning: the imp module is deprecated in favour of importlib; see the module's documentation for alternative uses
  mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.4\apps\qgis-ltr\python\plugins\db_manager\db_plugins\postgis\plugin.py:350: DeprecationWarning: invalid escape sequence \:
  uri = u"raster:gdal:%s:%s" % (self.name, re.sub(":", "\:", self.gdalUri()))
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.4\apps\Python37\lib\site-packages\PyQt5\uic\objcreator.py:152: DeprecationWarning: 'U' mode is deprecated
  plugin = open(filename, 'rU')
```

And everything works fine.

I guess we can rely on QGis and Pyqt teams to keep their libs up to date before the warnings become errors.

Comment: my script worked for u?

Comment: @AN10 your script worked for me exactly like you: no error, just deprecation warnings (different warnings than the ones I have though). There is no output because the script does not have a `main` routine.

Comment: so should  i just add a `main ` that returns the output ?

Comment: @AN10 yes I guess

Answer (score 0):

Your script has the definition of the processing algorithm class but in order for it to do something you need to instantiate the `Trees` class and use it.

Add this at the end of the file and then run it:

```
trees = Trees()
feedback = QgsProcessingFeedback()
context = QgsProcessingContext()
parameters = {} #add your parameters here
trees.initAlgorithm()
trees.processAlgorithm(parameters, context, feedback)
```